# PHP Echo Mysql Data from 2 tables BY newest data

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to echo the 10 newest data from 2 different tables. Ive tried

```
$stmt60 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM 54x2 ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt60->execute();
$stmt61 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dd ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt61->execute();
$row60 = $stmt60->fetch();
$row61 = $stmt61->fetch();
```

I also stored it in a ton of arrays like this:

```
$var = array($row60['date_time'], $row62['date_time'], $row64['date_time'], $row66['date_time'], $row68['date_time'], $row70['date_time'], $row72['date_time'], $row74['date_time'], $row76['date_time'], $row78['date_time']);
$var7 = array($row61['date_time'], $row63['date_time'], $row65['date_time'], $row67['date_time'], $row69['date_time'], $row71['date_time'], $row73['date_time'], $row75['date_time'], $row77['date_time'], $row79['date_time']);
```

did that about 10 times with offsets increasing by 1 then did like a 100 if statements checking whcih one is newer but ive tried for hours doing that and I couldn't get it to work. Is there an easier way of doing this without making 100-200 if statements?

Comment: Why would you need 200 `if`s? You can do one large select, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html, also if only pulling the date column dont use `*` use the column name. `ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5` will give you the 5 newest records (assuming that is a datetime column).

Comment: I think ive tried that but didnt work because columns are different and i did * because i am trying to echo more than just date_time i have like 10 more arrays that have the column names in it.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: UNION

This way the problem goes away. Column count should be the same, but You are in control of what You fetch so You could arrange for that by specifying the exact columns You fetch (unless these are completely different results and You need completely different data from each type)

SQL:

```
(SELECT date_time,a,b,c FROM table_a ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT date_time,a,b,c FROM table_b ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY date_time DESC
```

---

### Option 2: Single pass

The idea is to loop through both results once (together) each time comparing two current elements and moving one pointer (of the greater one) and keeping the second one intact - until You reach the end of both results

```
$stmt60 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM 54x2 ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt60->execute();
$stmt61 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dd ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt61->execute();

$row60 = $stmt60->fetch();
$row61 = $stmt61->fetch();
do
{
   if($row60 && (!$row61 || $row60['date_time']>$row61['date_time']))
   {
      var_dump($row60); // output row60
      $row60 = $stmt60->fetch();
   }
   if($row61 && (!$row60 || $row61['date_time']>=$row60['date_time']))
   {
      var_dump($row61); // output row61
      $row61 = $stmt61->fetch();
   }
}
while($row60 || $row61);
```

---

### Option 3: Merge and sort

I probably should not even mention this one, since both memory consumption and efficiency are far worse than option #2.

However, You can create a single array of all the elements fetched from both statements and then sort the result in php (by [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) or [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort))